# What is the difference between align and flalign?

Tags: align

I am wondering if there is some drawback of using one versus the other.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When there are multiple columns, `flalign` adds more space between the columns to occupy the whole text width, as explained in the documentation of `amsmath`:

> The environment `flalign` (“full length alignment”) stretches the space between
> the equation columns to the maximum possible width, leaving only enough space
> at the margin for the equation number, if present.

Indeed, consider the following example, where the vertical bars on both sides indicate the left and right margins.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    a & = b & c & = d
\end{align}
\begin{flalign}
    a & = b & c & = d
\end{flalign}
\end{document}
```